# Bootstrap remove gap between collapsible main menu and sub menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the gap between the main menu and the sub-menu. The "Add Student" is the main and the "Freshmen" and "Transferee" is the sub-menu.
      Here's the output:
[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p1" href="#pv1"><i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
      <p>Add Student</p></a>
      <ul class="nav collapse" id="pv1">
        <li>
          <a href="user.html"><i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>
                                    <p>Freshmen</p></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="user.html"><i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>
                <p>Transferee</p></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What if you just remove the `<p>Add Student</p>` and replace it with `Add Student`?

Comment: Inspect `<ul class="nav collapse" id="pv1">` since there's most likely `margin` styles that are creating the gap between the two menus.

Comment: It did'nt work.

Comment: thanks Jeff P. I added style="margin-top: -30px; margin-bottom: -10px" to the <ul>

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sidebar-wrapper .nav > li > a{
  padding:5px 15px;
}

.nav > li > a p{
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#p1" href="#pv1"><i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
                    <p>Add Student</p></a>
                    <ul class="nav collapse" id="pv1">
                        <li>
                            <a href="user.html"><i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>
                                <p>Freshmen</p></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="user.html"><i class="material-icons">add_circle</i>
                              <p>Transferee</p></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Change `padding` as per your need.

Is this the same that you are looking for?

Hope this helps.